# Number is randomizing repeatedly per click

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a mini-game that revolves around numbers randomizing and score being allocated depending on whether the number displayed is a multiple of 'x' in this case 3.

However, I have an issue, because for some reason whenever the player clicks to randomize, it randomizes several times completely throwing my score system.

So far, I have attempted to solve this issue through the use of:

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

However, this proved to be for naught as it did not help.

If any of you could shed some light on why this is happening it would be deeply appreciated.

**Code in use**

```
void Awake ()
{
    randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
}

void Start()
{
    mycam = Camera.main;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    StartCoroutine(Selection ());

    thisAnswer.text = randomNumber.ToString ();
}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update ()
{
    if (CorrectCount == 5) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("MiniScore", miniScore);
        Destroy (GameObject.Find ("Killswitch"));
    }
}

IEnumerator Selection ()
{
    Ray ray = mycam.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
        {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "answer") 
            {
                if (System.Convert.ToInt32(thisAnswer.text) % 3 == 0) 
                {
                    miniScore = miniScore + 100;
                    CorrectCount = CorrectCount + 1;
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                    randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
                    Debug.Log (miniScore.ToString());
                } 
                else if (System.Convert.ToInt32(thisAnswer.text) % 3 != 0) 
                {
                    if (miniScore > 50) 
                    {
                        miniScore = miniScore - 50;
                    } 
                    else if (miniScore < 50) 
                    {
                        miniScore = 0;
                    }
                    Debug.Log (miniScore.ToString ());
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                    randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect whats happening here is that this line of code

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Mouse0))
```

is getting executing several times a once the user presses the mouse button - GetKey will return true as long as the button is down (which is will be for several frames - So you could try

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Mouse0))
```

This should only fire once when the mouse button is released.

Check out

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html